# HTML: Sort and display CSV file by specific column data

Tags: html, csv

I have a multi-row multi-column CSV file like this:

```
name1,family1,2012,m
name2,family2,2016,f
name3,family3,2014,m
```

So far, I am using the following html code to display full content of the CSV file.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style> table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border: 2px black solid;
            font: 12px sans-serif; }
        td {
            border: 1px black solid;
            padding: 5px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"charset="utf-8">
        d3.text("teaching.csv", function(data) {
            var parsedCSV = d3.csv.parseRows(data);
            var container = d3.select("body")
                .append("table")
                .selectAll("tr")
                    .data(parsedCSV).enter()
                    .append("tr")
                .selectAll("td")
                    .data(function(d) { return d; }).enter()
                    .append("td")
                    .text(function(d) { return d; });
        });
    </script>
</body>  </html>
```

I need to alter html code to:
 1) only display data of second column for all rows and 2) sort rows by numbers in third column, (largest at the top)

Any help would be appreciated.